# is it possible to convert SVGPath to Mesh in javafx

Tags: svg, javafx, mesh, .obj, svg-path

I am trying to convert .svg file to 3d (.obj file) using javafx.

I can able to convert primitives like Shape - Cylinder, Box etc to Mesh. Is it possible to convert SVGPath to convert to any particular Mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open source library [FXyz](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz) has exactly what you are looking for: a [`SVG3DMesh`](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/master/FXyz-Core/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/shapes/primitives/SVG3DMesh.java) class that given a 2D `SVGPath` (or a string with its content) will return a 3D TriangleMesh, extruding the 2D shape to a certain height.

Later on you can export that mesh to a obj file.

This is a code snippet of how you can use it:

```
SVG3DMesh svg3DMesh = new SVG3DMesh("M40,60 C42,48 44,30 25,32", 10);
```

[image: SVG3DMesh]

You can show the mesh:

```
svg3DMesh.setDrawMode(DrawMode.LINE);
svg3DMesh.setCullFace(CullFace.NONE);
```

or show a solid 3D object with the color you want:

```
svg3DMesh.setTextureModeNone(Color.RED);
```

For exporting the mesh to obj:

```
OBJWriter writer=new OBJWriter((TriangleMesh) ((TexturedMesh) svg3DMesh.getMeshFromLetter("")).getMesh(), "svg");
writer.setMaterialColor(Color.RED);
writer.exportMesh();
```

it will generate svg.obj and svg.mtl.

Comment: Pereda, Thank you so much for your comments. This will really help me to understand the process behind the conversion.

Comment: @José Is it also possible to create a flat (non-extruded) mesh that way?

Comment: @mipa Yes, indeed, that's the first part of how the 3D mesh is generated: The 2D closed path uses Poly2Tri to generate a 2D mesh. You'll need to add some API to get that mesh out of SVG3DMesh...

Comment: @José Wouldn't that be a reasonable default behaviour for the cases where you do not explicitly specify a height or, if that is not possible due to backwards compatibility issues, if you specify a negative height?

Comment: @mipa it is a 3D library... so it generates full 3D objects. But it can be extended to return 2D meshes as well, it just needs the API to get them once they are generated.